# Procedure in oracle wont run

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
  -- procedure--
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDBUSERByUserId(
   p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
   o_username OUT DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE,
   o_createdby OUT  DBUSER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
   o_createddate OUT DBUSER.CREATED_DATE%TYPE)
 IS
BEGIN
 SELECT USERNAME , CREATED_BY
 INTO o_username, o_createdby
**FROM  DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = p_userid;
END;

 DECLARE
 o_username DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE;
 o_createdby DBUSER.CREATED_BY%TYPE;
 o_date DBUSER.CREATED_DATE%TYPE;

 BEGIN
 GETDBUSERBYUSERID(1001,o_username,o_createdby,o_date);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('username :  ' || o_username);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('createdby :  ' || o_createdby);
END;
```

- DBUSER TABLE COLUMNS:
- USER_ID,
- USERNAME,
- CREATED_BY,
- CREATED_DATE,

  Error report -
  ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the        following:

  ;  
  The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

  6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
        *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
        *Action:'

I am trying to test out a procedure because I am teaching myself how to due them because of lack of teaching at my school on anything past the basics. I am running this code inside of Oracle sqldeveloper program, and I can not figure out what it means by I am reaching the end of the file, because I installed a 1 data member to match the code inside. I do not want to show the date it was added so that is why it is not in the declare statement.

Comment: When you paste code, don't paste line numbers. Mark out the lines you're getting an error on using a comment.

Comment: You've figured out the first problem, so can you show the actual code that gets the second one instead? Including the final `/` if you have one, and say how you're running it.

Comment: @AlexPoole just did a re-edit and what do you mean by a final '/' ??

Comment: You have two things here, a procedure definition and an anonymous block. Are you running them both together as a single script? (Looks like SQL Developer?) If so you need a slash on a line on its own between them - and after the anonymous block - to execute each block independently. It looks like the error is coming from the `END` in the procedure, but it's not 100% clear. You've shown it with a trailing semicolon, but not the submitting slash.

Comment: okay that seemed to work, This is the minor stuff we were not taught in our class when working with databases. I appreciate the help @AlexPoole. That did solve the problem and it finally completed the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running everything you've shown as a script, you need a `/` after each independent section of PL/SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDBUSERByUserId(
   p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
   o_username OUT DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE,
   o_createdby OUT  DBUSER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
   o_createddate OUT DBUSER.CREATED_DATE%TYPE)
 IS
BEGIN
 SELECT USERNAME , CREATED_BY
 INTO o_username, o_createdby
 FROM  DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = p_userid;
END;
/

DECLARE
 o_username DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE;
 o_createdby DBUSER.CREATED_BY%TYPE;
 o_date DBUSER.CREATED_DATE%TYPE;
BEGIN
 GETDBUSERBYUSERID(1001,o_username,o_createdby,o_date);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('username :  ' || o_username);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('createdby :  ' || o_createdby);
END;
/
```

[This documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref291) if for SQL*Plus, but mostly applies to SQL Developer too.

Comment: Yeah it did work after i installed the /....there are somethings that the education system lacks when teaching students